# Is there a way to get discord user's data from a uid without a module in javascript?

Tags: javascript, discord

I'm making a small website for my bot where people can look at stats of other users.
My database stores all users with their uid, but now I need to get their name somehow only using that uid. If it can be done in javascript that'd be preferable.

I thought there would be a way to do it from discord, like an API or something. I tried searching but found nothing.

Edit: A similar project to the one I want to make is [this website](https://discord.id/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
const {Client} = require('discord.js')

const token = 'YOUR_TOKEN'

const client = new Client()
client.token = token

const fetchUser = async id => client.users.fetch(id)
```

The result of `fetchUser` would be a discord.js `User` object.

Comment: I keep getting a 401 "UnAuthorized" error. I put in the token and everything but it doesn't work

Comment: can you share a fiddle or something to show what you are doing? Cross check the token, is it expired.

Comment: sorry for the late response. I've made a repl.it with the code. https://repl.it/@OmerSabic/discordAPIProblem#index.js

Comment: I figured it out, I made some slight adjustments to your code and now it works perfectly fine. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @DontAsk_ Great !!

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
message.channel.author
```

In Discord.js to get the username of the person who sent the message.

Comment: I'm looking to get the username from the uid on a webpage, not my bot.